# Installing Flamenco software

Tags: add-on

I am interested to give the [Flamenco](https://www.flamenco.io) software a try. The software and documentation can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/armadillica/flamenco). After reading the Readme I really don't understand how to install this software on my Mac and Windows machines. As this software facilitates a blender render farm I thought I can ask here if anyone can help me to install that software.

Comment: if you do try to install again, perhaps you should make a new question with what part of the installation process you're stuck on. As it is your question is too broad.

Comment: As one of the Flamenco developers: I agree with Luciano, your question is overly broad. We're still writing documentation, so it's not complete yet, and concrete information about what is unclear or simply missing would really help us in that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the development team:

> Flamenco is undergoing some changes right now, so I would recommend
>   you wait with testing it out. Please check out the website again in a
>   couple of months, or follow what we are doing on cloud.blender.org to
>   spot any news in Flamenco development.